# pyspark withColumn issue

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Basically,

Input Pyspark Dataframe is below

```
a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 9 0 9 0 0 0 0 0  
2 0 9 9 0 0 0 0 0 
3 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 0  
4 0 0 9 9 0 0 0 0  
5 0 0 9 0 9 0 0 0  
6 0 0 9 0 0 9 0 0  
7 0 0 9 0 0 0 9 0  
8 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 9
```

i want output to be

```
a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 4 0 9 0 0 0 0 0  
2 0 4 9 0 0 0 0 0 
3 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0  
4 0 0 9 4 0 0 0 0  
5 0 0 9 0 4 0 0 0  
6 0 0 9 0 0 4 0 0  
7 0 0 9 0 0 0 4 0  
8 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 4
```

I did some research that, i need to use **withColumn** and **replace** function to accomplish my task.

How i can query value from Column **a** and use that value as a column name to replcae  **9** to **4**

Please suggest solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.select("a", *(F.when(F.col("a")==F.lit(int(x)),F.lit(4)).otherwise(F.col(x)).alias(x)\
                 for x in df.columns if x!='a')).show()

#+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  a|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  1|  4|  0|  9|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
#|  2|  0|  4|  9|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
#|  3|  0|  0|  4|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
#|  4|  0|  0|  9|  4|  0|  0|  0|  0|
#|  5|  0|  0|  9|  0|  4|  0|  0|  0|
#|  6|  0|  0|  9|  0|  0|  4|  0|  0|
#|  7|  0|  0|  9|  0|  0|  0|  4|  0|
#|  8|  0|  0|  9|  0|  0|  0|  0|  4|
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: you really awesome murthihash. Thanks for resolving my issue.

i have small question, it is to understand your code.

why you used *(star symbol) infront of list comprehension.Please let me know

Comment: Thank you. It unpacks the list for you. Also if any function in pyspark.sql docs has * in the () , it means that it’s able to unpack a list [] or generator () of column expressions for you